# como puedo crear un select dinámico con js y mysql que además este select contenga un buscador?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, select, ejs

estoy intentando crear un select para traer datos de un crud para registrar ventas en un mysql pero como es una gran cantidad de datos necesito un select que tenga buscador y que sea dinámico para mostrar la cantidad de productos disponibles y además que todo ese select se pueda duplicar para agregar un nuevo producto en el mismo registro y la verdad no se como hacerlo ayuda por favor

```
<div class="mb-4">
   <label for="">Elige El Producto</label>
   <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
     <% for (let i = 0; i < producto.length; i++) { %>
     <option value=""><%= producto[i].nombre_producto%></option>
                                 <% } %>
   </select>
   <label for="">stock disponible </label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stockProd">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [Select2](https://select2.org/) te ofrece un cuadro de selección personalizable con soporte para búsqueda, etiquetado, conjuntos de datos remotos, desplazamiento infinito y muchas otras opciones muy utilizadas.

```js
 // In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" style="width: 100%;">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AL">Alaska</option>
<option value="AL">Vue</option>
<option value="AL">React</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: pero como lo hago con una base de datos es que estuve leyendo la documentación pero gran parte es de php y no js y nesesitp traer los datos de mysql

Comment: solo ingresas la lista que queres traer desde tu base dentro de la etiqueta `select`, sabes majear `php`?

Comment: no php no lo manejo y cómo es un proyecto de ejs mucho menos pero con ejs logre que me muestre los datos pero no el buscador

Comment: necesitaría ver tu código de `php` y como haces para insertar las cosas que traes desde la base de datos!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una librería, llamada Select2. Lo puedes usar con CDN:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Luego con el select que ya tienes en tu código:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.form-select').select2(); 
});
```

Recuerda que Select2 necesita jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```